# Locked out of my Mac - Help!

Tags: mac, keyboard

I have an older Macbook Pro, 15" that I picked up on eBay. I had been letting my mother use it for the past year.

Somehow she (or someone else) changed her password. Now she uses an external keyboard (USB, Apple made) because sometime ago the I and K keys stopped working on the built in one. Going into single user mode to reset the password I noticed that while I can hold Apple+S on the external keyboard to boot into it, it won't let me type through it.

There are a series of commands to mount the operating system and change the password for a user, all use an I or K.

I've tried another USB keyboard no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_reset_my_mac_os_x_admin_root_password.html), you can just boot off the OS X install disk and pick "Reset Password" from the Utilities menu.

The instructions [here](http://theappleblog.com/2008/06/22/reset-os-x-password-without-an-os-x-cd/) don't require either the CD, or the letters "i" and "k".

Comment: Would be great, if I still had the disc.

Comment: @Josh - If you have a local Apple Store they might let you borrow a cd for a few moments at the store.

Comment: Josh, if you look at the second link in my message, it does mention a way that doesn't require the CD.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to enter I & K through the use of ascii sequences.  You enter them with the option key, and a list can be found [here](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/Professeurs/Alain/files/ascii.htm).

Comment: This didn't work.

Answer (score -3):

Boot using the Apple system CDROM - there's a utility included to reset the system password. If you're keys are shot, I suggest getting an external USB keyboard in case you need it.

Good luck.

Comment: Read the question, where he explains that he already has an external keyboard but it doesn't help.  And that he tried a second one.

Comment: Sorry CarlF and Josh K - I missed the details about the external keyboard, but your system CD should do the trick.